# Sharepoint 2013 Footer Placeholder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, ajaxdelta

I'm new to Sharepoint, and I'v just got responsible for applying the branding style of my company to it, actually I'm stuck at this footer thing.
Goggling around people say that I just need to create a DIV element at the bottom of the masterpage, but I refuse to take this as an answer, where is the module thing going, webparts and so on?
I found this piece of code in the "oslo.master" page, which I believe that is responsible for dynamically printing a footer when it is needed. I hope someone understands how it works, and where would I put my HTML code so that it appears at this placeholder, which is actually printing and empty DIV with the ID "DeltaPlaceHolderFooter".

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false" />
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Comment: Every blog or other source of information on internet, have only grotesque solutions for everything related to sharepoint... like printing a script tag to hide something, which could be done with CSS only, there are people writing huge tutorials just to say how to select a element with CSS... After years of coding experience, using frameworks and design patterns, is Sharepoint really that mess? Or wasn't it mean to be customized? Is there a hero kind MVP out there who wants to give a little hand here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage of that control, the PageFooter delegate control, is to create an ASP.NET ASCX User Control (or purely C# code based ASP.NET UserControl) and register it with that control ID. I have blogged about how to use delegate controls here: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/. In my example I am registering with the AdditonalPageHead control.  Just replace that with the PageFooter control ID.

Comment: As of July 26, 2018, this site link you've referred us to is "Not Found."